# How to clone a hdd or raid live?

Tags: backup, hard-disk

Is there a way to clone my ubuntu server without shutting it down or booting into rescue mode?

Comment: Can you stop or quiesce the application(s) for some time so that no files are being written to? Do you need bit-for-bit identical disks on the destination, or is it enough that all the files are identical at destination? Does your server live on snapshot-capable SAN storage, or do you have LVM, a snapshot-capable filesystem, or any other mechanism in place that allows filesystem snapshots? Do you need a fully automated solution or are you able to do some manual work?

Comment: Ideally I don't want to stop applications as that would have the same effect of shutting down the server... I'm not sure I need bit-for-bit identical disks, it's a dedicated remote server I access with SSH, I can do manual work

Comment: you should see fsfreeze. It could help you but it's quiet hard what you want. It is really dependant of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clone unless you have snapshottable disks (ZFS, BTRFS, LVM).

You can copy relatively static files from the filesystem using a tool such as `rsync` (or even `scp` at a pinch). Note that "relatively static" excludes files used within a running database, almost certainly even if it's not being actively used at the point of the copy.